# Having problem with brown driver?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while running brown driver following is the problem

```
$ rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/bin/driver.py", line 138, in  
driver = CreateDriver()
File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/bin/driver.py", line 21, in **init**
self.create = Create(port)
File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/bin/irobot/create.py", line 144, in **init** 
self.reset() 
File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/bin/irobot/create.py", line 175, in reset 
self.__read(128,True) 
File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/bin/irobot/create.py", line 221, in __read 
bytes = self.port.read(num) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyserial-2.6-py2.7.egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 446, in read 
ready,*,* = select.select([self.fd],[],[], self._timeout)
select.error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72607/having-problem-with-brown-driver?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The dependencies were not resolved .......... the packages on which the package is dependent is installed and the problem got solved.

---

Originally posted by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) with karma: 205 on 2013-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0